# mp3 to flv on the server side how to?

Tags: php, mp3, flv, server-side

I googled it for a long time, all I found was the ffmpeg php api, and a site called mp32tube .. now I was to have the exact same functionality of mp32tube I want to give my users the ability to upload an mp3 add a picture, then compile an FLV on the server that contains the picture and the mp3...

the rest I can do, like uploading the video to youtube, it's simple with their own API ..

can anyone please guide me to something that automatically does this on my server?  (a centos powered VPS)

thank you very much.

Rami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read FAQ first.
http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14

then to add sound you may try;

```
 ffmpeg -ar 22050 -ab 128k -i song.mp3 -i videoHaveNoSound.flv VideoWithSound.flv
```

Let me know the result.

in addition:

you findout a shorter way;

```
 ffmpeg -r 12 -b 1800 -i img.jpg -i yourSound.mp3 -acodec copy outVideo.flv
```

Comment: dude i wish there was a "you saved my butt" button .. amazing it worked for me (the first one, didn't try the edit yet) .. now all i need to do is a simple validation process to prevent users from uploading non 128k audio files, i want to follow a simple standard best to say :D .. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is no "automatic" way to do this.  You'll have to have the user upload the 2 pieces of data, then run them through ffmpeg.  There is tons of documentation for ffmpeg out there, just research the command you'll need to run, test it outside of php first, then once you get it working, implement it in your script.  After its gone through ffmpeg, delete the files used for creation, and let them download the resulting flv.